# Upgrading to Paperclip 4.3 from 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm rewriting an old Rails 2.3 application in Rails 4.2, preserving the database contents.

So far so good.

The old app used the Paperclip 2.3 plugin and stored the files on S3.
On the new app I installed the Paperclip 4.3.6 gem and aws-sdk 2.3.

My issue: when I call the avatar for whatever existing user, for example

```
User.first.avatar
```

the app returns:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

I've installed ImageMagik and added

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

to my development.rb

Here are my model/controllers:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:micro => "32x32#", :thumb => "50x50#", :big_thumb => "80x80#", :small => "220x220>", :featured => "220x220#", :medium => "600x600>"}#, :default_url => 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/ccu-static/file.small.png'

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], :if => lambda {|user| user.avatar_file_name}

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end

end
```

config > initializers > paperclip_defaults.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    def self.default_options
      @default_options ||= {
        :storage           => :s3,
        :url               => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :path              => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :styles            => {},
        :processors        => [:thumbnail],
        :convert_options   => {},
        :default_url       => "/images/missing.:style.gif", #"http://s3.amazonaws.com/ccu-static/missing.:style.png", 
        :default_style     => :original,
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
        :whiny             => Paperclip.options[:whiny] || Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails]
      }
    end
  end
end
```

config > S3.yml

```
production:
  bucket: ...
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
development:
  bucket: ...
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "avatar_file_name",           limit: 255
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
```

view:

```
<%= image_tag(@top_players_score[0].avatar.url(:thumb)) if @top_players_score[0].avatar %>
```

Anyway I get the same error even from the console with a basic:

```
user.avatar
```

Comment: Can you show your view

Comment: Added the view code, although I get the same error even from the console with user.avatar